# Backbone - testing a simple model using Jasmine results in TypeError

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine

I was trying to learn the ways of testing Backbone-based app using Jasmine. For this, I picked up some sample code from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/hh377172.

```
    Photo = new Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            title: 'Another photo!',
            tags:  ['untagged'],
            location: 'home',
            src: 'placeholder.jpg'
        },
        initialize: function(){
            console.log('this model has been initialized');
            this.bind("change:title", function(){
                var title = this.get("title");
                console.log("My title has been changed to.." + title);
            });
        },

        setTitle: function(newTitle){
            this.set({ title: newTitle });
        }
    });
```

Then wrote the test spec as follows:

```
    describe("Photo Model", function() {
        it("verifies title", function() {
        var myPhoto = new Photo();
        myPhoto.set({ title: "On the beach" });   
        expect(myPhoto.get("title"))
            .toEqual("On the beach");
        });
    });
```

While running it, the test fails with TypeError

```
    TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'
        at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:88/backbone/WebClient-Backbone2/js/backbone.js:1103:41)
        at [object Object].<anonymous> (http://localhost:88/backbone/WebClient-Backbone2/test/spec.js:28:16)
        at [object Object].execute (http://localhost:88/backbone/WebClient-Backbone2/test/lib/jasmine/jasmine.js:1001:15)
        at [object Object].next_ (http://localhost:88/backbone/WebClient-Backbone2/test/lib/jasmine/jasmine.js:1790:31)
        at [object Object].start (http://localhost:88/backbone/WebClient-Backbone2/test/lib/jasmine/jasmine.js:1743:8)
        at [object Object].execute (http://localhost:88/backbone/WebClient-Backbone2/test/lib/jasmine/jasmine.js:2070:14)
        at [object Object].next_ (http://localhost:88/backbone/WebClient-Backbone2/test/lib/jasmine/jasmine.js:1790:31)
        at [object Object].start (http://localhost:88/backbone/WebClient-Backbone2/test/lib/jasmine/jasmine.js:1743:8)
        at [object Object].execute (http://localhost:88/backbone/WebClient-Backbone2/test/lib/jasmine/jasmine.js:2215:14)
        at [object Object].next_ (http://localhost:88/backbone/WebClient-Backbone2/test/lib/jasmine/jasmine.js:1790:31)
```

Comment: It seems the error is throw line 28 of your spec.js. Have you post the whole spec file here?

Comment: The whole code is as above. i.e. the definition of **Photo** and followed by the the spec definition. So, line 28 is: `  var myPhoto = new Photo();`

Comment: Looks like the problem is caused by the "new" being performed twice. After I removed the "new" from the Model definition, the problem spec got executed and passed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I found out that, this is due to the "new" in the model definition.

So, after changing,

```
    var Photo = new Backbone.Model.extend({
```

to

```
    var Photo = Backbone.Model.extend({
```

The error disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good set of tutorials for testing a backbone based application with Jasmine here:
http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/03/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon.html

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet below is probably the culprit.

```
this.bind("change:title", function(){
  var title = this.get("title");
  console.log("My title has been changed to.." + title);
});
```

In Javascript, the scope context of the **this** keyword is based upon the function it is in. Since **this** is inside an anonymous function (this.bind("change:title", **function()**), then **this** has changed its scope.

The easy solution is to use a closure to set **this** to another variable outside the anonymous function, and then you can use the variable inside the anonymous function.

Showing a code example will probably better explain it. Update your initialize method to the following.

```
    initialize: function(){
        console.log('this model has been initialized');
        var self = this;
        this.bind("change:title", function(){
            var title = self.get("title");
            console.log("My title has been changed to.." + title);
        });
    },
```

You will also have the same problem in the **setTitle()** method. You will need to add this line of code in the **initialize()** method to correctly set the context of **this**.

```
_.bindAll(this, "setTitle");
```

Comment: Makes sense. But, after I removed the "new" from the Model definition the problem went away. No other change!

Comment: Now, I wonder - why didn't the spec fail again? Does it mean, Backbone is internally taking care of binding "this" appropriately ? I am confused now.